# How can I create a Folder and create a new text file inside this folder simultaneously

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a new folder in my `C:` drive, but also trying to create a new text file to store some information. Now, this code below creates the folder, but the text file part gives me the following error - "**file access denied**". I am still new with Delphi and would appreciate any help with the following.

```
procedure TfrmLogin.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  user: string;
  tf: textfile;
begin
  if DirectoryExists('c:/' + Edtuser.Text) then
    ShowMessage(Edtuser.Text + 'folder exists')
  else
  begin
    if CreateDir('c:/' + Edtuser.Text) then
      ShowMessage('Login succesfull')
    else
      ShowMessage('Login unsucessfull!Please try again');
  end;

  user := Edtuser.Text;
  system.AssignFile(tf, 'C:\' + user + '.txt');

  system.rewrite(tf);
  system.Writeln(tf, edtPass.Text);
  system.closefile(tf);
```

Comment: The text in the edit is the folder you create. Say it's name is "folder", you now have C:\folder. You are trying to create the file C:\folder.txt. Review your AssignFile.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz How do i resolve this problem , because i want to name the text file according to the name of the folder

Comment: Not sure I understand, probably `'C:\' + user + '\' + user + '.txt'`

Comment: found a way to resolve the problem.@SertacAkyuz

Answer (score 0):

Operating system versions as of today won't let you create files on their system root by default: Windows 7 did this already, and Windows 10 goes the same route. Make sure you are able to create i.e. `C:\user.txt` at all - if not, change permissions. Hence the OS IO error "access denied" - it has nothing to do with Delphi and is quite precise.